# Random invalid syntax in python

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying out some stuff in python using the pygame module. this is my code:

```
import pygame, sys
direction = " "
pygame.init()
try:
 while True:
  for events in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
      sys.exit()
    elif event.type == pygaqme.KEYDOWN:
      if event.key == pygame.K_w:
        forward = True
      elif event.key == pygame.K_a:
        left = True
      elif event.key == pygame.K_s:
        reverse = True
      elif event.key == pygame.K_d:
        right = True
    elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
      if event.key == pygame.K_w:
        forward = False
      elif event.key == pygame.K_a:
        left = False
      elif event.key == pygame.K_s:
        reverse = False
      elif event.key == pygame.K_d:
        right = False
  if forward:
    print ("forward")
  elif left:
    print("left")
  elif reverse:
    print("reverse")
  elif right:
    print("right")
```

And on executing this, python tells me that line 35 has invalid syntax, but the problem is that my code is only 34 lines long. I checked to see if there was an accidental new line created and it turns out there was. So I deleted that and executed it again but I still got the same error.

Comment: You've begun a `try` statement (used to catch an exception) and not finished it an `except`, which would appear on line 35 *at the latest*.  Is the `try` necessary here? If so, add an `except`; otherwise, you can remove it.

Comment: Whenever you get a "random syntax error" like this, it almost always means either (1) you're missing a `)`, `]`, or `}` on the previous line, or (2) you've got a `try:` without any `except:`/`finally:` farther up the current block.  (And if it's not one of those, the next thing to look for is mixing tabs and spaces and hiding problem (1) or (2).)

Comment: @abarnert There should be some canonical question on SO for this type of Python problem, with the answers that you have just provided.  Do you know of one?

Comment: @SethMMorton: No. Every once in a while I search for one, which just reminds me of how hard of a question it is to search for even if you know the problem (much less for the poor person who's encountering this for the first time and has no clue what's wrong…).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Python is looking for a `except:` or `finally:` block; you cannot just open a `try:` block without one of those.

Since there was no such block by the time the last line is reached, you get the syntax error for that last, empty line. Line 35 in your case.